# Two fans video card in a micro atx and GA-Z97X-Gaming 5 motherboard

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I have a Gigabyte GA-Z97X-Gaming 5 motherboard and I am thinking to place an X16 PCI express video card like the GTX 1660 Ti or Super with 2 fans.

When looking at the motherboard and case it seems the memory slots will be pretty close to the video card and also the heatsink block of the CPU is close to x16 slot (3cm as shown in the image).
Do you think a card such as GTX 1660 Ti or Super with 2 fans will fit?
I prefer to place it on the x16 slot rather than the x8 slot which is actually in a better location in the motherboard for such big card (the big one below the highlighted x16 in the image).
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that it *should* fit.

Expansion cards should be designed to fit the ATX size standard.  So when it comes to slots, they technically should fit, even if its tight.

Motherboard manufacturers design their boards knowing large, heat producing graphics cards are going into the x16 slot.  Again, it should work.

Both of these being the case, that doesnt mean there arent the occasional times where something doesnt fit.  However, there is no way for us to know, unless someone has that exact setup.

Comment: The distance between the heatsink and the GPU might be extremely small, but it should still fit, you do have one of the largest heatsinks on the market.

Comment: It's pretty big, I think it's Noctua NH-U9B, from the x16 slot center to the heatsink we have 3cm max. Would 3cm be enough in your opinion? also, I am worried about the memory slots. as Keltari said, i'll have to find someone with a similar setup.

Comment: 3cm is plenty of space